# What is A "Gateway Interface"?

Tags: networking, interface, tcp, gateway

In the book "
The .NET Developer’s Guide to Directory Services Programming" and the the section titled "Definition of LDAP", the following paragraph is written:

*The Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) specification was ratified in July 1993, in RFC 1487. Its inventors at the University of Michigan originally created it as a complement to the heavier-weight DAP X.500 protocol. At first, the LDAP designers just wanted a simple **gateway interface** to X.500 for the TCP/IP protocol that was easy to implement and program against. The idea was that the LDAP server component would translate LDAP calls into their corresponding DAP X.500 calls, and would translate the X.500 server responses back into LDAP for the client.*

My question to you kind people is precisely this: what do they mean when they say `gateway interface`? What is a gateway interface? What are some examples of gateway interfaces? What does a gateway interface do?

Many a kind 'thank you''s to those whom answer.

-TP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also known as Common Gateway Interface (CGI), you may see this pop up here and there.

> The Common Gateway Interface (CGI) is a standard (see RFC 3875: CGI
>   Version 1.1) method for web server software to delegate the generation
>   of web content to executable files. Such files are known as CGI
>   scripts; they are programs, often stand-alone applications, usually
>   written in a scripting language.

[Common Gateway Interface Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)